# ¿Por que la referencia es ambigua?

Tags: c++, template

```
template <class A, class B> struct is_same{};

template <class A, class B>
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<A, B>::value; //reference to 'is_same' is ambiguous
```

También me sale con este:

```
template<class T, class U> struct is_same : std::false_type {};
 
template<class T> struct is_same : std::true_type {};

template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value; //reference to 'is_same' is ambiguous
```

Comment: Tienes algun `using namespace std;` en algun lado? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387600/reference-to-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Te dice que la referencia es ambigüa porque hay, al menos, dos elementos diferentes que podrían coincidir con el uso de `is_same`. Llegados a este punto, el compilador no tiene forma de saber qué versión debe utilizar y de ahí el error.

En este caso, además de tu implementación de `is_same`, fíjate que esta función también existe bajo el espacio de nombres de [`std`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Normalmente no pasa nada porque esta función se encuentra dentro del espacio de nombres `std`. Sin embargo en tu caso se dan las 3 circunstancias necesarias para que se produzca el error:

- El nombre de tu plantilla coincide con el de `std`
- Importas el espacio de nombres `std`
- De forma directa o indirecta estás incluyendo `type_traits` en tu código

Tienes tres posibles soluciones:

- Dejas de importar el espacio de nombres `std`
- Cambias el nombre a tu función
- Incluyes tu función dentro de un espacio de nombres que no sea `std` (y, por supuesto, evita la tentación de incluir dicho espacio de nombres o volverás a tener el mismo problema)